# Does the use of linked images on a webpage slow loading speed?

Tags: html

By linked images, I mean having an image in a directory and giving the path to the image in order to set an objects display or background.  I've noticed that since using this method, my page is taking a considerable amount of time to load.  So if this is the issue, what would be the alternative?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain what you mean? I don't really get the question :)

Comment: Can you post your HTML to give us an example ?

Comment: Well, I had been using very simple images I made in MS paint for the prototype and the website was running smoothly.  Then I made some more detailed flash images and the site is creeping along, seeming to load pixel by pixel.

Comment: How are you defining load time?

Comment: In no scientific way, I'm saying it is noticeably slower loading.  The images themselves seem to be slowing everything down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the Firebug addon for Firefox.

It breaks the loading time down and explains how long each thing takes to load.

But from your question i would say no, it shouldn't add any extra loading time on.
(I assume you mean loading an image from /index/pictures compared to /index/)

EDIT: Looking at your comments you say "more detailed image"... does this mean a larger file size and if so how large?

You can answer your question yourself by using firebug, We can't without asking a lot more questions since you have left so much needed information out. :/

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the location of the file, your browser still has to obtain the file. The key word there, is **browser**.

The data (regardless of type) is downloaded to the client (browser).

Regarding image size, try reducing image size, there are plenty of programs out there (I've found VSO image resizer rather useful in the past)

Remember, slow loading webpages effect SEO!